How to Update Multiple Custom Properties at Once
TLDR
Is there a way to update the parameters of multiple custom properties at once using a script.
Context
Using an outdated addon I was able to generate and link shape keys to a bones custom properties, so they can be edited while remaining in pose mode. Now I have a list of shape keys for my meshes all controlled by one bone. However the script created an error where the min and max of the newly made custom properties are infinite so when I modify them with click and drag they are impossible to fine tune. So they're functional, just annoying to tweak. I'd like to reset their minimum, maximum and subtype to be nicer to animate with.
Using my limited scripting experience and a few hours of blind googling I was able to scrape together a script that edited the custom properties one by one, but that doesnt save much time and I would like to be able to reuse the script with the addon for future projects. I believe the key to this lies in having the script call each property's name place it in the bone.id_properties_ui(), but when I try using a key() function to call up a list of prop names it wont accept them in the bone.id_properties_ui(). Again im a super noob to scripting so I could be way off the mark so I'd appreciate any help offered.
My Rough Script
import bpy

rig = bpy.context.active_object
bones = [bone for bone in rig.pose.bones]
active_bone = bpy.context.active_pose_bone

for bone in bones:
    bone.id_properties_ensure()
    property_manager = bone.id_properties_ui("MouthShapeA")
    property_manager.update(
    default=0.0,
        min=-10.0,
        max=10.0,
        subtype="FACTOR",
        precision=2
    )

